# awk, extract string between different delimiters

Tags: xml, awk, extract

I have xml file as below:

```
<Name ns1:translate="yes">Overview</Name>     
<TextValue>Start</TextValue>
<Title ns1:translate="yes">This is a "book"</Title>
<Title>BOOK</Title>
<Description ns1:translate="yes"/>
<TextValue ns1:translate="yes">End</TextValue>
```

I want to extract the strings if the tag contains translate="yes". The output should look as below:

```
Overview = Overview
This is a "book" = This is a "book"
   = 
End = End
```

I need to do the above extraction using shell script. I tried to use:

```
awk awk -F '["<>]' '{if (/.*translate="yes".*/) {print ((NF>6?OFS $(NF-2):x))}
```

But it is not giving me desired result as the "book" in the output is not getting printed. Please let me know what would be wrong in the above awk.

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool like `xsltproc` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like tripleee suggests, you should use an xml-parser. For a dirty solution using `awk`, you could do:

```
awk -F '[<>]' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /translate="yes"/) print $(i+1), "=", $(i+1) }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Overview = Overview
This is a "book" = This is a "book"
 = 
End = End
```

This solution will just print the next element after finding `translate="yes"`. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

```
>awk 'BEGIN{FS="<|>"}/translate="yes"/{split($2,a,">");print a[2]"="a[2]}' temp
Overview=Overview
This is a "book"=This is a "book"
=
End=End
```